# How to do if/else statement and print it out with console.log

Tags: javascript

Write your own if / else statement. The only instruction is that the result of evaluating the statement is a log to the console of "I finished my first course!". ? How do you finish it?

Comment: If you're doing a codecademy course I don't think the point is to ask for the answer on stackoverflow

Comment: If you want people to help you, you should show that you have put some effort in first.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide. Not only can you learn about `if/else` statements, but also about many other aspects of JavaScript.

Comment: [Hopefully this does the job](https://jsfiddle.net/rnd88prp/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Ha! Think you should Google a bit more, but at the risk of doing your homework for you:

```
if(true) {
    console.log("I finished my first course!");
} else {
    // do nothing
}
```

Enjoy!